# Comparing two filtered tables in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a Power BI table thas contains a comparison of two other filtered tables. I am getting stuck on creating a DAX formula.

The two tables are:

- Cases (contains case number, 'Case_ID')
- Statuses (Contains type of status, 'Status_Type' and status number, 'Status_Number')

Each Case_ID can have multiple types of statuses, all with different status numbers. Statuses are not linked to particular status numbers. Status_Description describes which status a case has, and Status_Number indicates the order in which this status occurs.

For example, the case 345677 will first have status A, and then status F etc. and finally will have status M:

| Case_ID | Status_Type | Status_Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 345677 | StatusA | 1 |
| 345677 | StatusF | 2 |
| 345677 | StatusT | 3 |
| 345677 | StatusX | 4 |
| 345677 | StatusB | 5 |
| 345677 | StatusM | 6 |

Each Case_ID will have different statuses at different points in time. Sometimes a case can have only a few statuses, and sometimes it has 12. Each status type (Status_Description) can only occur once for each Case_ID.

This is how a different Case_ID could for example look:

| Case_ID | Status_Type | Status_Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 345678 | StatusZ | 1 |
| 345678 | StatusY | 2 |
| 345678 | StatusB | 3 |
| 345678 | StatusU | 4 |
| 345678 | StatusK | 5 |

I am trying to make a table where I can see per Case_ID which Status_Type - StatusA or StatusB -occurred first in time (has a lower Status_Number). In this example, I expect to get a table like this as output:

| Case_ID | A or B first? |
| --- | --- |
| 345677 | StatusA |
| 345678 | StatusB |

How can I create this in Power BI?

Comment: > "Each Case_ID can have multiple types of statuses."

Do you have a table apart from status and case table which holds one to many relationship as shown in examples?

Comment: Yes I have many other tables in my model, but these are the only relevant ones for this problem. Do you need more information?

Answer (score 1):

```
Measure :=
VAR _0 =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( 'fact'[Status_Number] ),
        'fact'[Status_Type] IN { "StatusA", "StatusB" }
    )
VAR _1 =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'fact'[Status_Type] ), 'fact'[Status_Number] = _0 )
RETURN
    _1
```

[image: Solution]

The first variable determines the Min number per CaseID for A or B. The 2nd variable returns the Min Type for the first variable.